# How can I make builds appear incrementally in a slidify presentation?

Tags: r, rstudio, slidify

I am using slidify in RStudio to prepare a presentation. How can I make builds (for example single paragraphs) appear incrementally in a single slide at each click? {Build:} does not seem to work with slidify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Slidify, you can specify slide classes along with the slide separator. So for example.

```
--- {.build}

## Slide

1. > Point 1
2. > Point 2
```

Comment: Thank you Ramnath! this is exactly what I was meaning and what I needed!

Comment: You might want to add more details to the question so that it is taken off hold. You can use the example on the RStudio page to explain what you are trying to do, and then state that you are trying to achieve the same using Slidify.